# Error with use of PdfDictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, itext

I am making use of `PdfDictionary` and writes the following

```
PdfDictionary sv = new PdfDictionary();
sv["/Type"] = new PDFName("/SV");
sv["/Filter"] = new PDFName("Abc");
sv["/Ff"] = new PDFNumber(1);

signame.Dictionary["/SV"] = sv;
PDFArray arReasons = new PDFArray();
arReasons.Add(new PDFString(string.Format("CToken::{0}", customxml)));
arReasons.Add(new PDFString(reason));
v.Put(PdfName.arReasons);
```

But it gives me the following errors searched a lot but no positive outcomes

```
Error   1   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary'  C:\Users\lenovo\Dropbox\updated C# app\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form2.cs   134 17  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

the other errors that i get are:-

```
Error   9   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName' does not contain a definition for 'arReasons' C:\Users\lenovo\Dropbox\updated C# app\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form2.cs   145 32  WindowsFormsApplication1

Error   3   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Dictionary' and no extension method 'Dictionary' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\lenovo\Dropbox\updated C# app\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form2.cs   141 25  WindowsFormsApplication1

Error   8   The name 'reason' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\lenovo\Dropbox\updated C# app\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form2.cs   144 45  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

Just in case someone helps me with too

Comment: looks like PdfDictionary class does not support indexing as it does not expose any array type behavior.

Comment: seems like same any work around possible

Answer (score 2):

`PdfDictionary` keys are `PdfName` objects, so if there was an indexing operator, you couldn't use a `string`.  Since `PdfDictionary` doesn't appear to implement an indexing operator, you would do this:

```
PdfDictionary sv = new PdfDictionary();
sv.Put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.SV);
sv.Put(PdfName.FILTER, new PdfName("Abc"));
sv.Put(PdfName.FF, new PdfNumber(1));
```

Note the use of static members that are already set to those names and that you don't need to prefix any name strings with a '/'.

Also, **please** make sure that you check the syntax and semantics of your output.  iTextSharp doesn't do this for you (to my knowledge) and the end result is a damaged PDF that maybe Acrobat will accept silently, but are a pain for every other PDF consumer.  I write PDF tools for a living and routinely question the marital status of the parents of other PDF producers when I see missing keys that are required, null required values, unparsable date time strings and names in dictionaries that read //Foobar instead of /Foobar (just to name a few).

Comment: Furthermore @user1862352 references a PdfName.arReasons. I doubt very much there is such a static element in the iTextSharp PdfName class.